# how to redirect edit form in spring MVC using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**In view Form we have edit button when i click the edit button i need to go edit page with Data from database but i cannot able to redirect to edit page itself**

Ajax in view Form:

```
'click .edit': function (e, value, row, index) {
                var val=JSON.stringify(row);
                alert('You click like action, row: ' +val);             
                jQuery.ajax({ 
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "EditShop", 
                    dataType:"json", 
                    data:JSON.stringify(row) ,

                    processData:false,
                    success : function(data) {
                        console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
                        display(data);
                        alert('sucess');
                    }, 
                    error : function(e) {
                        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                        display(e);
                    },
                    done : function(e) {
                        console.log("DONE");
                    }
                }); 

            },
```

Spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/EditShop" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public @ResponseBody shopModel editShop(@RequestBody shopModel shop) {

          System.out.println("Inside Edit Shop : "+shop.getStoreName());

          return shop;
      }
```

Comment: can you check that your request hit in that request mapping?

Comment: I can able to see in output screen @RequestMapping is called,but editShop method is not executed ,i dont know how to call editShop.jsp page from  controller with specific data from the database     @ CHiRAG

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/EditShop" , method = RequestMethod.POST,  produces = "application/json") add produces property in your request mapping

Comment: I am using above one but getting Exception org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Comment: in that case please remove @RequestBody annonationa and 'produces' from the request mapping

Comment: @CHiRAG Is response produces will redirect to some other page? Don't you this ajax and normal request has different behaviour

Comment: @HarshalPatil - ya its tru but i just want to know that request is handled in request mapping or not

Comment: @AjithCsE you need to redirect to edit page using jQuery only. In request success specify edit page url using window.location.href = "URL"

Comment: @CHiRAG read his question again

Comment: I am remove above one but getting null values in editShop method            Inside Edit Shop : null
DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.sample.pojo.shopModel com.sample.Controller.shopController.editShop(com.sample.pojo.shopModel)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Comment: @HarshalPatil - ya i had read it.

Comment: please go through the description

Comment: @AjithCsE so why you need to give ajax call. You can directly submit post form data and handle your call in the controller itself. No need to use ajax

Comment: using ajax to redirect to another page makes no sense. The whole point of ajax is to avoid redirects, postbacks etc. If you need to redirect, use a normal postback and save yourself the trouble, since you have to reload the page anyway.

Comment: If you need redirect to another page, the you can do like   window.location = '/<appName>/edit'